# How to retain TeX code using TeX4ht

Tags: tex4ht

Kindly suggest latex to xml cfg code to get the following:

(1)
LaTeX:

```
$D$
```

XML:

```
<inline-formula>
<tex-math><![CDATA[
$D$
]]>
</tex-math>
</inline-formula>
```

(2)
LaTeX:

```
\begin{equation} 
\label{eq7} 
\Lambda \left(x\left| {y_{1},\ldots,y_{p}} \right.\right)=\frac{\Lambda 
(y_{1},\ldots,y_{p},x)} {\Lambda (y_{1},\ldots,y_{p} )},
\end{equation}
```

XML:

```
<disp-formula id="s1234-E7">
<label alt="equation 7">(7)</label>
<tex-math><![CDATA[
\begin{equation} 
\label{eq7} 
\Lambda \left(x\left| {y_{1},\ldots,y_{p}} \right.\right)=\frac{\Lambda 
(y_{1},\ldots,y_{p},x)} {\Lambda (y_{1},\ldots,y_{p} )},
\end{equation} 
]]>
</tex-math>
</disp-formula>
```

Comment: If you use `\verb| ... |` in the LaTeX code then `tex4ht` will not change the contents in the HTML output.

Answer (score 4):

The following code is modified version of the [mathjax-latex-4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/blob/master/mathjax-latex-4ht.sty) package. Save it as `myaltmath.sty`:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox,expl3,environ}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \alteqtoks #1
{
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\detokenize{#1}}
  % delete spaces before left brackets
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \x{20} \x{7B} } { \x{7B} } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl{ \l_tmpa_tl }
  \HCode{\l_tmpb_tl}
}

\newcommand\inlinemath[1]{#1}
% #1 math type, #2 math contents
\newcommand\displayblockmath[2]{#2}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\AltMathOne#1${\inlinemath{\alteqtoks{#1}}$}
  \Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMathOne} 
  \def\AltlMath#1\){\inlinemath{\alteqtoks{#1}}\)}
  \Configure{()}{\AltlMath}{}
  \def\AltlDisplay#1\]{\displayblockmath{math}{\alteqtoks{\[#1\]}\]}}
  \Configure{[]}{\AltlDisplay}{}

\newcommand\VerbMathToks[2]{%
  \displayblockmath{#2}{%
  \alteqtoks{\begin{#2}
    #1
  \end{#2}}}%
}
\newcommand\VerbMath[1]{%
\ifcsdef{#1}{%
  \RenewEnviron{#1}{%
  \NoFonts\expandafter\VerbMathToks\expandafter{\BODY}{#1}\EndNoFonts%
  }
}{}%
}
\VerbMath{align}
\VerbMath{equation}
\VerbMath{equation*}
\VerbMath{align*}
\VerbMath{cases}
\VerbMath{array}
\VerbMath{matrix}
\VerbMath{pmatrix}
\VerbMath{eqnarray}
\VerbMath{eqnarray*}
}
```

The configurations which insert the required XML tags are saved in companion configuraton file, `myaltmath.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{InlineMath}{2}
\pend:defI\inlinemath{\a:InlineMath}
\append:defI\inlinemath{\b:InlineMath}
\Configure{InlineMath}{\HCode{<inline-formula>\Hnewline
<tex-math><![CDATA[\Hnewline$}}{\HCode{$\Hnewline]]>\Hnewline
</tex-math>\Hnewline
</inline-formula>\Hnewline}}

% configure display math
% we want to save the math type info to an XML attribute, so we need to use three hooks
\NewConfigure{DisplayMath}{3}
\renewcommand\displayblockmath[2]{\a:DisplayMath#1\b:DisplayMath#2\c:DisplayMath}

\newcounter{DisplayMathCount}

\Configure{DisplayMath}{\stepcounter{DisplayMathCount}\HCode{<disp-formula id="s1234-E\arabic{DisplayMathCount}" type="}}{\HCode{">\Hnewline
<tex-math><![CDATA[\Hnewline}}
{\HCode{\Hnewline]]>\Hnewline
</tex-math>\Hnewline
</disp-formula>\Hnewline}}
%<label alt="equation 7">(7)</label>
```

Important thing is that the `\displayblockmath` configuration inserts the `type` attribute, which can be then used for DOM manipulations. Because the LaTeX code is saved verbatim, it is not possible to add the `<label>` element from the TeX side, it must be done in the post-processing stage.

To require the `myaltmath` package, use the following configuration file:

```
\RequirePackage{myaltmath}
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The post-processing can be done using the [LuaXML](https://github.com/michal-h21/LuaXML) library in the `make4ht` build file (`mybuild.mk4`):

```lua
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"

local counters = {}
local function stepcounter(countertype)
  -- retrieve counter type value, or initialize a new one
  local currentval = counters[countertype] or 0
  local newval = currentval + 1
  counters[countertype] = newval
  return newval
end
local process = domfilter {
   function(dom)
     -- process all equations and make label with their equation number
     for _, equation in ipairs(dom:query_selector("disp-formula")) do
       if equation:get_attribute("type") == "equation" then 
         local count = stepcounter("equation")
         local label = dom:create_element("label", {alt = "equation " .. count})
         label:add_child_node(label:create_text_node(string.format("(%i)", count)))
         equation:add_child_node(label, 1)
       end
     end
     return dom
   end
}

-- replace the html$ with extension which you actually use, probably xml$
Make:match("html$", process)
```

Please note that I've found some bugs in LuaXML when I wrote this build file and it will take some time before the fixed version will be on CTAN. You can use the development version in the meantime.

To compile, use the following command

```
make4ht -uc myconfig.cfg -e mybuild.mk4 filename.tex
```

This is the result in HTML:

```html
<!-- l. 6 --><p class='noindent'>Some text <inline-formula> 
<tex-math><![CDATA[ 
D 
]]> 
</tex-math> 
</inline-formula> 

</p><!-- l. 12 --><p class='indent'>   <disp-formula id='s1234-E1' type='equation'><label alt='equation 1'>(1)</label> 
<tex-math><![CDATA[ 
\begin{equation} \label{eq7} \Lambda \left (x\left |{y_{1},\ldots ,y_{p}} \right .\right )=\frac{\Lambda (y_{1},\ldots ,y_{p},x)}{\Lambda (y_{1},\ldots ,y_{p} )}, \end{equation} 
]]> 
</tex-math> 
</disp-formula> 

</p>
```

As you can see, the white space is a bit messed up in the TeX code, this is a  consequence of the `\detokenize` command. I am not sure that it can be fixed.

Comment: we are getting the following error message

Output dir:  
Compiler:  latex
Latex options:   -jobname=math 
tex4ht.sty : myconfig.cfg,,charset=utf-8
tex4ht  -cmozhtf -utf8
build_file mybuild.mk4
Using build file mybuild.mk4
[string "local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"..."]:1: module 'make4ht-domfilter' not found:
 no field package.preload['make4ht-domfilter']
 [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'make4ht-domfilter'
 [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'make4ht-domfilter'
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/mkutils.lua:290: assertion failed!

Comment: @Purushothaman which TeX distribution do you use? It seems that it contains older version of `make4ht`. It is best to use TL 2018. You may also try to install the development version of `make4ht`.

Comment: We are using TeXLive 2015, ubuntu 16.04. We have updated the latest make4ht from the github.

.../texmf/scripts/lua/make4ht/filters/make4ht-domfilter.lua:2: module 'luaxml-domobject' not found:
 no field package.preload['luaxml-domobject']
 [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'luaxml-domobject'
 [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'luaxml-domobject'
/home/threetwo/texmf/scripts/lua/make4ht/mkutils.lua:413: assertion failed!

Comment: @Purushothaman TL 2015 is really old, many things will be broken. The particular error message you got means that you need to update also [LuaXML](https://ctan.org/pkg/luaxml?lang=en). But as I said, you may have a better luck with updated TL.

Comment: DOM parsing of math.html failed:
...ive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:174: Unbalanced Tag (/tex-math) [char=457]

parse_lg process file: math.html
outdir: 
parse_lg process file: math.css
outdir: 
parse_lg process file: math.tmp
tmp file

Comment: Also $$ is missing before the inline math.

Comment: @Purushothaman it seems that you have old version of `LuaXML`, it had issues with parsing XML files that contains `<![CDATA`. This issue should be fixed now, but I discovered another issue in the distributed version, so I just updated it and it may take few days before TL gets the correct version. You can update then using `tlmgr update --all`.